# Microsoft Dependency Injection Documentation

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

In the documentation for dependency injection I notice the following line.

> The MVC framework will automatically look at the service provider to
>   register our dependency in the Controller.

They then provide a basic example with constructor injection, not their example but in essence this.

```
public class Example
{
     private IFooFactory foo;

     public Example(IFooFactory foo) => this.foo = foo;

     public void SampleUse()
     {
          using(var context = foo.Create())
              context.DoSomething();
     }
}
```

If you have a console application, by default it will not look at the service provider to register your dependency with the concrete implementation.  Is there a way to simulate that?  Otherwise the console application will require you to do something along these lines:

```
public static Main(string[] args)
{
    // Stuff to prepare the application and build service provider.
    var service = serviceProvider.GetService<IFooFactory>();
    using(var context = service.Create())
        context.DoSomething();

    // OR

    var fooFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<IFooFactory>();
    new Example(fooFactory).SampleUse();
}
```

Which creates the problem of having to pass `IFooFactory` or pulling things into the main that you may wanted separated for structure.    How can I make the console application look at the provider when a new class is created with a defined interface?

Comment: You might be able to use [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor) to help with this. I’ve not used it myself but I’ve seen it come up a few times recently.  Combining that with [`ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities.createinstance?view=aspnetcore-2.1) might have you covered.

Comment: @KirkLarkin I will check it out.

Comment: Take a look at the concept of the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/). Your Main method is the application's Composition Root and this is the place to register and resolve from.

Comment: @Steven Thank you, I will take a look.  Always anxious to learn, so appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create everything manually as the framework is not there to automagically do it for you.

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddTransient<IFooFactory, FooFactory>();
services.AddTransient<Example>();

IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

Example example = serviceProvider.GetService<Example>();

example.SampleUse();
```

While not ideal, it is usually the way shown in most examples where DI is configured manually.

When you inspect the framework DI integration, behind the scenes it does the exact same thing during startup.

You could probably write your own code to inspect available types, but that is a very broad task to tackle on your own.

Reference [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1#default-service-container-replacement)

> ## Default service container replacement
>
> The built-in service container is meant to serve the needs of the
>   framework and most consumer apps. We recommend using the built-in
>   container unless you need a specific feature that it doesn't support.
>   Some of the features supported in 3rd party containers not found in
>   the built-in container:
>
> - Property injection
> - Injection based on name
> - Child containers
> - Custom lifetime management
> - `Func<T>` support for lazy initialization

Comment: True, but is that the ideal way?

Comment: "You could probaly write your own code to inspect available types," seems like something that should be built in core though.  Not only their web framework, but the console applications, and any other that utilizes core.

Comment: @Greg the built in DI in core was meant to be a small module to satisfy basic requirements. Auto discovery and registration are advanced features. This is also why the MVC framework also allows you to swap out the built in DI for your 3rd party DI of choice.

Comment: Bummer, because that seems like a feature that would be incredibly valuable in most cases.  They had it in Unity, but oh well.